# retrieving selector id's from an array of selectors

Tags: jquery, arrays

In the following snippet I a get an array of selectors with the class data_table.

I am trying to get the id of each of those selectors, which now that im posting I can probably get in the array statement, but anyway I cannot get the right syntax to find the id of the array objects. The array DOES contain the right items.

```
var pageName = GetCurrentPageName(true);
var datatables = $(".data_table").toArray();
var arrayLength = datatables.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    ' errs here, with no .val or with .text or with childNodes[0].data() which is what i see in dev tools
    var tableId = datatables[i].attr('id').val();
    alert(tableId);
    var searchString = 'webpagename[name ="' + pageName + '"] > tableid[id ="' + tableId + '"]';
}
```

Comment: Use: `$(".data_table").each(function(){ var tableId = this.id; /* your other code here */ });`

Comment: Consider using jQuery.each - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: post as answer and Ill accept

Comment: @Joe, I think he's talking to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) instead:

```
var pageName = GetCurrentPageName(true);

$(".data_table").each(function(){
    var searchString = 'webpagename[name ="' + pageName + '"] > tableid[id ="' + this.id + '"]';
});
```

Keep in mind that `searchString` won't be accessible outside the `.each()` loop. If you need it to be used outside the loop then consider using something similar to what Dhanasekar S M proposed in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery terms that you have used are a bit irrelevant. But I got what you need.

Please look into this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u2LhW/

Sample:

```
var divs = $('div.clsdiv');
    var ids = [];
    $.each(divs,function(i,val){
        ids.push($(val).attr('id'));
        console.log($(val).attr('id'));
    });
```